# Why is the do_nothing method needed for C++ singleton instantiation?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost

I was going over the documentation from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/pool/detail/singleton.hpp

My question: since create_object is a static member of class singleton_default its constructor should be called before main. From the constructor of object_creator, singleton_default::instance is called, which makes sure obj is instantiated before main. What I don't follow is the need for the do_nothing method. The documentation mentions it forces the instantiation of create_object but are not static members of class supposed to be initialized before main starts? By that token should singleton_default::create_object instantiation not be good enough?

Here's the code

```
// T must be: no-throw default constructible and no-throw destructible
template <typename T>
struct singleton_default
{
  private:
    struct object_creator
    {
      // This constructor does nothing more than ensure that instance()
      //  is called before main() begins, thus creating the static
      //  T object before multithreading race issues can come up.
      object_creator() { singleton_default<T>::instance(); }
      inline void do_nothing() const { }
    };
    static object_creator create_object;

    singleton_default();

  public:
    typedef T object_type;

    // If, at any point (in user code), singleton_default<T>::instance()
    //  is called, then the following function is instantiated.
    static object_type & instance()
    {
      // This is the object that we return a reference to.
      // It is guaranteed to be created before main() begins because of
      //  the next line.
      static object_type obj;

      // The following line does nothing else than force the instantiation
      //  of singleton_default<T>::create_object, whose constructor is
      //  called before main() begins.
      create_object.do_nothing();

      return obj;
    }
};
template <typename T>
typename singleton_default<T>::object_creator
singleton_default<T>::create_object;
```

I tried removing the do_nothing method, but that stopped the object instantiation before main.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the standard in section ***3.6.2 initialisation of non local variables***.

First the principle in point 2:

> Variables with static storage duration (...) shall be zero-initialized
>   before any other initialization takes place.
>
> Constant initialization is performed:  (...)
>
> Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called
>   static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic
>   initialization. Static initialization shall be performed before any
>   dynamic initialization takes place. Dynamic initialization of a
>   non-local variable with static storage duration is either ordered or
>   unordered. Definitions of explicitly specialized class template static
>   data members have ordered initialization.

Then in point 4, the explanation for your question (your singleton requiring a "dynamic intialisation") :

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a
>   non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the
>   first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some
>   point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before
>   the first odr-use of any function or variable defined in the same
>   translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

This `do_nothing()` just ensures this first use and the order of the dynamic initialisation.

Wouldn't you have the `do_nothing()`, the global static `create_object()` wouldn't be needed to be initalized before your first call of `instance()`, and the static `obj` inside this function would only be initialized at first call, i.e. after the start of  `main()`.