# Global variable from a library not yet initialized when used

Tags: python, c++, initialization, global-variables, swig

### **The context :**

I created a module (I call it Hello) for Python in C++. The interface between C++ and Python is made by Swig. It generates a dynamic library `_Hello.so` and a Python file `Hello.py`. Then, when created, I juste have to call it by this way :

```
python
>>> import Hello
>>> Hello.say_hello()
Hello World !
>>>
```

I want to protect this module with a license, then I want the license is loaded when the module is imported.

### **My implementation :**

In order to be sure the license is loaded when I import the module, I created a singleton instanciating a global variable :

File `LicenseManager.hpp` :

```
class LicenseManager
{
  private:
    static LicenseManager licenseManager; // singleton instance
  public:
    static LicenseManager& get(); // get the singleton instance

  public:
    LicenseManager();  // load the license
    ~LicenseManager();  // release the license
  private:
    LicenseManager(const LicenseManager&);  // forbidden (singleton)
    LicenseManager& operator = (const LicenseManager&); // forbidden (singleton)
};
```

File `LicenseManager.cpp` :

```
LicenseManager LicenseManager::licenseManager;  // singleton instance

LicenseManager& LicenseManager::get()
{
  return LicenseManager::licenseManager;
}

LicenseManager::LicenseManager()
{
  /*
   * Here is the code to check the license
   */
  if(lic_ok)
    std::cout << "[INFO] License found. Enjoy this tool !" << std::endl;
  else
  {
    std::cerr << "[ERROR] License not found..." << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error("no available licenses");
  }
}

LicenseManager::~LicenseManager()
{}
```

This works perfectly ! When I load my module, I obtain :

```
python
>>> import Hello
[INFO] License found. Enjoy this tool !
>>> Hello.say_hello()
Hello World !
>>>
```

### **My problem :**

Actually, the code checking the license in my constructor uses the library *Crypto++*. I have a segmentation fault coming from this library but the same code in the main function works perfectly. Then I think that Crpyto++ also use global variables and these are not yet initialized when the constructor of `LicenseManager` is called.

I know there is no control on the initialization order of the global variables in C++. But maybe there is another way to do what I need better ?

### **Bad solutions :**

- If the singleton is not initialized as a global variable, the module is not protected when imported. A solution could be add a check in each functionnality of the module, and force the user to call the LicenseManager before usage. It's not a solution for me because I can't rewrite all my module to impose that (the module is quite huge actually).
- In the Swig configuration file, I can add Python code called when the module is loaded. Then I have to compile `Hello.py` to prevent the user simply remove the call to the LicenseManager. But then it's a poor security because Python is easy to decompile.

Comment: The more canonical way to implement a singleton is using Scott Meyers proposal. You'll find a description of it in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549704/how-to-store-a-reference-of-a-singleton-class/23549834#23549834).

Comment: In this solution, the singleton variable is initialized when the first call to it is done. I need it before any call of the user. With this implementation, the user just has to don't call the instance and then work without license.

Comment: Can the approach discussed in this SO question help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701496/why-is-the-do-nothing-method-needed-for-c-singleton-instantiation  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Actually, it is possible with Swig to add C++ code called during the initialization of the library. Then I just had to add the following code in the Swig file :

```
%init%{
  LicenseManager::get();
%}
```